# ruby JSON.parse ParseError unexpected token

Tags: json, ruby

I am trying to get some code running that uses ruby (version 2.1.4, is this very old?) on Ubuntu 16.04.

It seems like it's struggling to parse a simple JSON string, maybe there is something wrong with my installation:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

string='{foo:{"bar":"foobar"}}'
parsed = JSON.parse(string)
p parsed["foo"]["bar"]
```

I get this error:

```
/home/avilella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at '{foo:{"bar":"foobar"}}' (JSON::ParserError)
    from /home/avilella/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from example_json.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `foo` in quotes:

```
JSON.parse('{"foo":{"bar":"foobar"}}')
# => {"foo"=>{"bar"=>"foobar"}}
```

Comment: I thought I had foo in quotes, you are right that makes it bad JSON.

Comment: original version has no quotes either: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57605473/revisions

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like it's struggling to parse a simple JSON string, maybe there is something wrong with my installation:

There's nothing wrong with your installation. Your "simple JSON string" is simply not a JSON string.

The JSON parser is failing to parse your string because your string isn't valid JSON. In other words: the parser is fully correct in rejecting the string.